# vuejs this.$refs for more than one element

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I have 4 selects:

```
         <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-3">
                <label for="stateSelect">Status</label>
                <select v-model="filterState" @change="search()" data-live-search="true" class="form-control" ref="stateSelect" id="stateSelect">
                    <option value="">Alle Status</option>
                    <option v-for="assignmentState in assignmentStates" v-bind:value="assignmentState.state">
                        {{ assignmentState.state }}
                    </option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-3">
                <label for="loadingSelect">Beladungsort</label>
                <select v-model="filterLoading" @change="search()" data-live-search="true" class="form-control" ref="loadingSelect" id="loadingSelect">
                    <option value="">Alle Standorte</option>
                    <option v-for="location in locations" v-bind:value="location.id">
                        {{ location.name }}
                    </option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-3">
                <label for="unloadingSelect">Entladungsort</label>
                <select v-model="filterUnloading" @change="search()" data-live-search="true" class="form-control" ref="unloadingSelect" id="unloadingSelect">
                    <option value="">Alle Standorte</option>
                    <option v-for="location in locations" v-bind:value="location.id">
                        {{ location.name }}
                    </option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-3">
                <label for="carrierSelect">Spediteur</label>
                <select v-model="filterCarrier" @change="search()" data-live-search="true" class="form-control" ref="carrierSelect" id="carrierSelect">
                    <option value="">Alle Speditionen</option>
                    <option v-for="assignmentCarrier in assignmentCarriers" v-bind:value="assignmentCarrier.name">
                        {{ assignmentCarrier.name }}
                    </option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And I had to refresh this dom elements with the selectpicker function to get bootstrap-select work in vuejs like this:

```
export default {
    name: "AssignmentList",
    data() { ....
},
updated() {
        $(this.$refs.stateSelect).selectpicker('refresh');
        $(this.$refs.loadingSelect).selectpicker('refresh')
        $(this.$refs.unloadingSelect).selectpicker('refresh')
        $(this.$refs.carrierSelect).selectpicker('refresh')
    }
```

is it possible to sum up these 4 `.selectpicker('refresh')` statements?

Or is it possible to group / flag these selects that I can refresh these elements all at once without type each  individually.

Comment: What do you mean sum up? make this in one line?

Comment: yes exactly. Or to group / flag these selects that I can refresh these elements all at once
without type each select individually.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a constant in a `constants.js` file or something and `import` them into your component. Something like this:

```
const refTypes = Object.freeze({
  stateSelect: "stateSelect",
  loadingSelect: "loadingSelect",
  unloadingSelect: "unloadingSelect",
  carrierSelect: "carrierSelect"
});
```

Then in your component have a method you call that does something like this:

```
Object.values(refTypes).forEach((type) => {
  $(this.$refs[type].selectpicker('refresh');
});
```

And I would probably do the same thing for `'refresh'` too

Comment: I can't write this Object.values statement in the updated() function, it gives me a syntax error.

Comment: What error is it giving you? Did you import your `refTypes` properly?

Comment: yes I import like this:  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: {AssignmentList},
    data: {
        refTypes: refTypes
    }
}).$mount('#app'); and put this Object.values(this.refTypes .. and got error "Uncaught Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: C:\xampp\htdocs\orders\assets\js\components\assignment\AssignmentList.vue: Unexpected token, expected "," (341:54)"

Comment: @goldlife it looks like you just have a small syntax issue. Can you create a fiddle like this and show your error and I will fix it? Thanks https://jsfiddle.net/boilerplate/vue